# What is different between COM interop in C# and F#?

Tags: c#, f#, outlook, com-interop

I've got some simple Outlook interop F# code using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook assembly. However, when I deploy this onto the customer machine, as soon as the application tries to do anything with the interop code, it goes pop because it can't locate the assembly - so I get a FileNotFoundException cascading up the application.

However, if I run the same code in C# (even if called via an F# assembly), it works fine.

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
Marshal.GetActiveObject "Outlook.Application" :?> Application
```

Sadly the code works fine on my machine so I can't reproduce the problem locally. But what I'm more interested in understanding is what is different between how F# and C# references this assembly? I've looked in the project files themselves and tried references in two forms. The first is essentially the form you get when you add a reference in an F# project through VS: -

```
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

I've also tried setting copy local to true and ensuring that the assembly in the deployed path - this didn't work (and shouldn't be required either - when using a C# application that does the interop, it correctly locates it).

A second form I've seen looks like this: -

```
<COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook">
  <Guid>{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>9</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>6</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>primary</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
```

Along with a couple of other Interop assemblies.

However, neither option worked - how do F# projects differ from C# ones here?

Comment: what error message do you see?

Comment: There are rather a lot of differences.  Most important one for this exception is that the F# compiler does not support interop type embedding.  So you have a runtime dependency on the interop library, unlike your C# project.  Select the Outlook reference in your project's References node, in the Properties window set the Copy Local property to *True*.  Build your project and you'll now get Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll in your build directory.  You need to deploy this file as well to avoid the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: Good thing I haven't tried COM interop with F# yet! I was thinking of porting the (essentially abandonded) EzAPI for SSIS

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately I have already tried Copy Local to true (as mentioned in the original question). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hmm, it gets pretty hard to guess why it can't find the assembly when you made sure it is deployed.  At least try to get a repro by removing it from your GAC so your machine resembles the client's machine.

Comment: Yeah, that would help. I ended up porting the code to C# to work around the issue - I wasn't sure if there was some obvious thing about the way F# works with COM that's explicitly different though.

Comment: wouldn't the fusion log help here? Should help to figure out what places it is trying to resolve the type.